# Character bones clamp to center of root bone original location

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging

Opened project and my character looks like this. I use blender for almost 2 years and never experienced this. The last two bones in the arms, legs and the whole torso clamps to the center of the root bone origin. When I move the meshes they stretch and warp to that point. If I move the object to the root or around the mesh shrinks and then mirrors. for some reason the head is fine and my other character is fine as well. I have tried the apply location/scale etc. I do not believe it has to do anything with using the NLA editor. I tried tried a repose with "rest Position" that didn't work. I see no issue with vertex groups or weight paint. I don't know what other information that may be of help. Please help

[image]

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I might use MC prep and just re-create the model.